# Can't print a specific line from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, mechanize, mechanize-python

So I currently have this code to read an accounts.txt file that looks like this:

```
username1:password1
username2:password2
username3:password3
```

I then have this (thanks to a member here) read the accounts.txt file and split it at the username and password so I can later print it. When I try to print line 1 with the username and password separate with this code:

```
with open('accounts.txt') as f:

    credentials = [x.strip().split(':') for x in f.readlines()]



for username,password in credentials:

    print username[0]
    print password[0]
```

It prints out this:

```
j
t
a
2
a
3
```

(These are the three lines I have in the text file, properly split, however it's printing all the lines and only the first letter of each line.)

I've tried a few different methods with no luck. Anyone have an idea on what to do?

Thank you for all your help. It's really appreciated. This is my second day programming and I apologize for such a simple question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`username` and `password` are strings. When you do this to a string, you get the first character in the string:

```
username[0]
```

Don't do that. Just `print username`.

Some further explanation. `credentials` is a list of lists of strings. It looks like this when you print it out:

```
[['username1', 'password1'], ['username2', 'password2'], ['username3', 'password3']]
```

To get one username/password pair, you could do this: `print credentials[0]`. The result would be this:

```
['username1', 'password1']
```

Or if you did `print credentials[1]`, this:

```
['username2', 'password2']
```

You can also do a thing called "unpacking," which is what your for loop does. You can do it outside a for loop too:

```
username, password = credentials[0]
print username, password
```

The result would be

```
username1 password1
```

And again, if you take a string like `'username1'` and take a single element of it like so:

```
username[0]
```

You get a single letter, `u`.

Comment: Hey, thank you for this. I just responded to Johnsyweb who had a similar answer to yours. :) Was curious if there's a way to print only the first line of the file? Or in that case the second, third, etc. by choice? Thanks again!

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed and it works perfectly! Thank you so much, man. I can't express how much both your help and Johnsyweb's help has been. :)

Comment: @Shtoops: Welcome to StackOverflow! "Thank you so much, man" is best expressed ["by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd like to say if this is your second day programming, then you're off to a good start by using the [`with`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement and [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) already!

As the other people already pointed out, since you are using `[]` indexing with a variable that contains a `str`ing, it treats the `str` as if it were an array, so you get the character at the index you specify.

I thought I'd point out a couple of things:

1) you don't need to use `f.readline()` to iterate over the file since the file object `f` is an iterable object (it has the `__iter__` method defined which you can check with `getattr(f, '__iter__')`. So you can do this:

```
with open('accounts.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        try:
            (username, password) = l.strip().split(':')
            print username
            print password
        except ValueError:
            # ignore ValueError when encountering line that can't be
            # split (such as blank lines).
            pass
```

2) You also mentioned you were "curious if there's a way to print only the first line of the file? Or in that case the second, third, etc. by choice?"

The [`islice(iterable[, start], stop[, step])`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) function from the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) package works great for that, for example, to get just the 2nd & 3rd lines (remember indexes start at 0!!!):

```
from itertools import islice
start = 1; stop = 3
with open('accounts.txt') as f:
    for l in islice(f, start, stop):
        try:
            (username, password) = l.strip().split(':')
            print username
            print password
        except ValueError:
            # ignore ValueError when encountering line that can't be
            # split (such as blank lines).
            pass
```

Or to get *every other* line:

```
from itertools import islice
start = 0; stop = None; step = 2
with open('accounts.txt') as f:
    for l in islice(f, start, stop, step):
        try:
            (username, password) = l.strip().split(':')
            print username
            print password
        except ValueError:
            # ignore ValueError when encountering line that can't be
            # split (such as blank lines).
            pass
```

Spend time learning [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) (and its [recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes)!!!); it will simplify your code.

Comment: Just saw this. Thank you so much for such an elaborate answer! I will definitely look into itertools. :)