# How to print particular lines in text file using python

Tags: python

Here is my input text file with three fields. (description, value, polarity)

```
this is good
01
positive
this is bad
-01
negetive
this is ok
00
neutral
```

So i need to get all descriptions based on the value field. For Ex: I want to print `"This is good"` when i check the if condition for `"01"`. Is there any way to do it. Please suggest me.

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073699/cant-print-a-specific-line-from-text-file possibly duplicate question..

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have verified that link, in that text file. Text is separated with ':' but my text file is diffrent. but i tried that code it doesn't work for my requirement.

Comment: [DUPLICATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009161/how-do-i-use-a-specific-line-of-a-text-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `grouper` recipe from [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) to iterate through the file in chunks of 3 lines:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest, imap
>>> def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
        "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
        # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
        args = [iter(iterable)] * n
        return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)


>>> with open('test.txt') as f:
    d = dict((val, (desc, pol)) 
             for desc, val, pol in grouper(3, imap(str.rstrip, f)))


>>> d['00']
('this is ok', 'neutral')
>>> d['00'][0]
'this is ok'
>>> d['01'][0]
'this is good'
```

**Notes:** In Python 3 use normal `map` instead (which no longer requires an import) and `izip_longest` is now `zip_longest`

Comment: Thanks, but i am getting the following error  " d = {val: (desc, pol) for desc, val, pol in grouper(3, imap(str.rstrip, f))}
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: @VittalCherala Oh are you on Python <=2.6? Updated now

Comment: @VittalCherala Just in case you misinterpreted me, I updated my code to be compatible with Py 2.6, you don't have to update your Python although it would be a good idea ;)