# How do I use a specific line of a text file in python?

Tags: python, file, text, readline

My text file is this:

```
467 119 635 231 234 858
786 463 715 745 729 574 856 806 339 106 487
798 791 392 916 177 115 948 871 525
```

As you can see, there are three separate lines with different number values. My mission is to sort them, but only the line they are on. So basically, i need to sort the first line from smallest to biggest, then the second line from smallest to biggest, and the same on the third line.

The program specifies that it needs to use the values from this .txt file. So what I am wanting to do is look at each line one at a time and deal with that line, sort it with code, and put it back out.

My question is this: How do I get python to just look at one line at a time?

I know that this code reads the first line:

```
f = open("numbers.txt", "r")
f.readline()
```

but I'm looking for something that returns just each line specifically, and that way I can work with my sorting code with that specific line.

Clarification: I'm not looking for help with the sorting, I'm just trying to figure out how to look at each line by itself at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for line in f:
    nums = map(int, line.split())
    # looks at one line at a time, you can sort it now
```

If you want them all loaded at once

```
nums = [map(int, line.split()) for line in f]
```

Now you can access it like `nums[0]`, `nums[1]` for each seperate line.

Comment: Yes i've tried that, but say I need to set that certain line to a variable so i can start messing with it's contents. All the for loop does is do 3 loops of the text until all 3 lines are posted!

Comment: okay, but say you print nums[0]. this prints the first number in each line. I'm trying to get to the point where nums[0] (or any other variable) will just bring up the first line, and then nums[1] (or something else as well) will bring up the second line. Maybe I'm just not seeing the correct way to call the lines themselves?

Comment: @Wes so you want all the numbers in the file loading into `nums` at once? That's not the impression I got when you said one line at a time but I'll update accordingly

Comment: THAT was more along the lines of what I was thinking. Thank you! And sorry for being so confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that will do what you want. just give it the path to the file and it will do the rest.

Note: It is a generator.

```
def read_sort(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield sorted(map(int, line.split()))


print list(read_sort(__path_to_file__)
```

Comment: You forgot to convert it to `int`s so `'10'` is less than `'2'` for example

Comment: I really just wanted to figure out this specific problem i was having, as the actual assignment (the sorting) is much more complex than what I stated, it involves radix sorting and whatnot.